# How to render lightbox with different url from image in view?

Tags: reactjs, lightbox, react-hooks

I am getting images from unsplash api, and I am able to render them on the page. I am implementing a lightbox to be able to render the high res pic of the images in the page. I dont know how to go forward, I will show some code.

```
const ImageList = ({ image, isLoaded }) => {
  // const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState('false');

  if (isLoaded) {
    return (
      <div className="spinner">
        <ReactLoading type="spin" color="blue" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const imgs = image.map(img => (
    <img
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.small}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
    />

  ));

  if (imgs.length === 0) {
    return (
      <p>No images</p>
    );
  }

  if (isOpen === true) {
    return (
      <Lightbox
        onCloseRequest={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        mainSrc=
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {imgs}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ImageList;
```

Comment: imgs renders correctly, but Im not sure how I can get the mainSrc to get img.urls.full instead of small. thankyou

Comment: You don't seem to be writing anything in the mainSrc attribute

Comment: True, because I dont know how to access the url being passed to img

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're doing there, but assuming you're getting some array of objects from Unsplash, just organize those src's inside your state, and then tell the lightbox what is the mainSrc, nextSrc and prevSrc. Did you see the documentation? Assuming that this is the library u're using, check this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-lightbox